# Blender over SSH crashes with X Error

Tags: workflow, linux, network

I am using Fedora 26 PCs and ssh to connect from one PC to the other.

Blender version 2.78c cannot run over a SSH connection, but surprisingly version 2.77a has no problem with that!

When I run blender 2.78c over a SSH connection, the main window briefly opens, but crashes within a second with an error message in the terminal:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  153 (DRI2)
Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (DRI2Connect)
Serial number of failed request:  11
Current serial number in output stream:  11
```

Obviously this is an X related issue, but it's strange that version 2.77a works just fine, but 2.78c does not...

Is this a bug or a new "feature" in the newer version?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce. Just downloaded and run blender-2.78c-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 on a remote machine and it's been working for several minutes now (I've displayed windows, added primitives, rendered). Remote machine has X.Org X Server 1.18.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Does forcing CPU usage (by running blender as `./blender-softwaregl`) result in the same error?

Comment: Yes, it gives exactly same error!
I have tried two 2.78c version: one installed via the Yum/RPM repository, and another one by unpacking the pre-compiled download from the blender website. All these 2.78c version have this error.
I have an old 2.77a, which works just fine......?!?!

Comment: Could it depend on the video driver used on the local and remote PCs? 

When blender executable runs on remote, but is displayed on local PC:

X Error happens when nouveau driver on remote and i915 driver on local PC.

No error when radeon driver on remote and i915 driver on local.

Could that be the reason?

Comment: I don't know really, but it seems like the problem depends on a specific configuration of local and remote drivers and software. I don't know what could have changed between the two versions of Blender.